# How do I implement textInput binding with OJET input text v5.2.0?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-component, oracle-jet

Knockout's `textInput` binding used to work with Oracle JET v3.2.0 `ojInputText` tag.

```
<input id="text-input" 
     type="text"
     data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputText', 
                              textInput: value}"/>
```

But now that every single component of Oracle JET v5.2.0 is a custom HTML component, `textInput` doesn't work anymore. I've tried these methods:

```
<oj-input-text id="text-input" textInput="{{value}}"></oj-input-text>
<oj-input-text id="text-input" data-bind="textInput: value"></oj-input-text>
```

Is there a way to make `textInput` work with `oj-input-text`?

I've checked the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojInputText.html) as well, but nothing is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by @Srishti, I can't use `textInput` with Oracle JET. So I created a Knockout Binding Handler to imitate the behaviour, which I believe others would find useful too:

```
<oj-input-text data-bind="textInputOJET: value"></oj-input-text>
```

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textInputOJET = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).focus(function(){
            $($(this).find('input')[0]).keyup(function(event){
                valueAccessor()(event.currentTarget.value);
            });
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {}
}

self.value = ko.observable();
self.value.subscribe(function(newValue){
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, and you can see why when you check the library.
In `ojinputtext.js`, the `_onKeyUpHandler` function specifically listens only for the Enter key and nothing else.

```
 _onKeyUpHandler : function (event) 
    {           
       if(event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER){
            this._SetValue(this._GetDisplayValue(), event);             
       }
    }
```

It's also not possible to modify this function from your viewModel, since `ojinputtext` is registered as a Composite Component at the end into OJET, and only then do you get access to it.

```
  oj.CustomElementBridge.registerMetadata('oj-input-text', 'inputBase', ojInputTextMeta);
  oj.CustomElementBridge.register('oj-input-text', 
                         {'metadata': oj.CustomElementBridge.getMetadata('oj-input-text')});
```

You could maybe do a workaround of wrapping a Jquery function around the input text that listens to every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right OJET way of doing that without custom KO bindings is with `rawValue` instead of `value` attribute, as covered in the docs/playground:

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-520/jsdocs/oj.ojInputText.html#rawValue

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-520/jetCookbook.html?component=textInput&demo=rawValue